# Dynamic row data is not inserting into the database

Tags: javascript, php

I am dynamically adding a row through select box. I am facing three problem with below code

1. I am able to create the new row but its in reverse order like (3,2,1) instead of (1,2,3).
2. Secondly, when i select another number to create that number of rows then then previous data don't delete instead new data append on it.
3. Thirdly dynamic rows data is not inserting into the database.

   ```js
   function addrow(x){
              alert(x);

           for (var l=1; l <= x-1; l++){
                                      $(function() {
      var k=4;
                                                 //  var addDiv1 = $('#table_row');
                                               //  var k = $('#table_row p').size() + 1;
   var index = 4;
   newRow = "<tr>" +
                   "<td><label>Select Pagelayout"+l+": </label></td><td><?php $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display'); 
                       // Check connection
                               if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                         die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                               }
                               else{              
                                     $sql = "SELECT name FROM layout";
                                       $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                        $select4 .= "<option  value='select'>". select ."</option>";
                                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                         $select4 .= "<option>".$row['name']."</option>";
                                                 }
                                       echo "<select name='layout.'l'.' id='layout.'l'.'>".$select4."</select>";
                         mysqli_close($dbLink);
                           }?></td></tr>"+
                   "<tr><td><label>Select Data"+l+": </label></td><td><?php $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display'); 
                       // Check connection
                               if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                         die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                               }
                               else{              
                                     $sql = "select file_name from data_file";
                                       $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                       $select5 .= "<option  value='select'>Select</option>";
                                       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                       $select5 .= "<option>".$row['file_name']."</option>";
                                                                  }
                                   echo "<select name='data.'l'.' id='data.'l'.'>".$select5."</select>";  
                         mysqli_close($dbLink);
                           }?></td></tr>";


   $('#myTable > tbody > tr').eq(k).after(newRow);
        //  $('#myTable > tbody > tr').eq(k-1).after(newRow);

       return false;
              
                                                                   });
               
           }  scrnselection.h.value=l;  
              alert(l);
                          
             
                }
   ```

   ```css
       
   >    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   >    {
           $screen_name = $_REQUEST['multiname'];
           $screen_scr = $_POST['scr'];
           $screen_header = $_POST['header'];
       //$screen_layout = $_POST['layout'];
      // $screen_data =  $_POST['data'];
       $screen_footer = $_POST['footer'];
       $num = $_POST['h'];

      echo $num;

       
      $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display');
                                   
      if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                               }
   $sql="SELECT screen_name from `multi_screen` WHERE name='$screen_name'";
        $check=mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql);


    if(mysqli_num_rows($check)>=1)
     
   $error= "Name already exist!";


   else
     { 
    for($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++){
   if(isset($_REQUEST['layout$i']))
   {
      $screen_layout = $_POST['layout$i'];

      echo $screen_layout;
   }
   if(isset($_REQUEST['data$i']))
   { 
           $screen_data = $_REQUEST['data$i'];
   } 
    $sql1="INSERT INTO `multi_screen` (screen_name, screen_scr, screen_header, screen_layout, screen_footer) VALUES ('$screen_name','$screen_scr','$screen_header','$screen_layout','$screen_footer')";

      $result1 = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql1) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));

        if (!$result1)
     {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
     echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" >  alert(\"Problem ocuured with server. Please try again later.\");   </script>";
       }

      else $accept= "Data Inserted !Continue with the process.";
   }

    mysqli_close($dbLink);
     //   header("Location: layout.php");
     }
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <form name="scrnselection" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
               <center>
             <?php if(!empty($error)) echo '<div class="error"><b>'.$error.'</b></div>'; ?>  
               <?php if(!empty($accept)) echo '<div class="accept"><b>'.$accept.'</b></div>'; ?> 

           <input name="h" type="hidden" id="h" value="0" />
           <label id="lab" style="visibility:hidden;"></label> <br/> 
               <table id="mytable">
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           <label for="multiname">Enter the name of screen:</label>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <input type="text" name="multiname" id="name" value="" />
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                        
                  <tr>
                       <td>
                           <label for="scrn">Select no. of screen:</label>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                          <select name="scr" id="scr" onchange="addrow($(this).val());">
                                   <option value="select" selected>select</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           <label for="header">Select Header:</label>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                            <?php
                           $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display'); 
                       // Check connection
                               if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                         die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                               }
                               else{              
                                     $sql = "select header_name from screen_header";
                                       $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                       $select .= "<option  value='select'>Select</option>\n";
                                       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                       $select .= "<option>".$row['header_name']."</option>\n";
                                                                  }
                                   echo "<select name='header' id='header_file'>".$select."</select>";  
                         mysqli_close($dbLink);
                           }
                               ?>            
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                    <tr>
                               <td>
                           <label for="pagelayout">Select Pagelayout:</label>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <?php

                             $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display');
                                   
                                    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                         die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                               }
                                     else {
                                       $sql="SELECT name FROM layout";
                                       $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                       $select1 .= "<option  value='select'>Select</option>\n";
                                       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                       $select1 .= "<option>".$row['name']."</option>\n";
                                          }
                                       echo "<select name='layout[]' id='layout_file'>".$select1."</select>";  
                              mysqli_close($dbLink);
                             }   
                           ?>       
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                       <td>
                           <label for="data">Select Data:</label>
                       </td>
                       <td>

                           <?php
                               $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display');
                                   
                                    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                         die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                               }
                               else{              
                                     $sql = "select file_name from data_file";
                                       $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                       $select2 .= "<option  value='select'>Select</option>\n";
                                       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                       $select2 .= "<option>".$row['file_name']."</option>\n";
                                                                  }
                                   echo "<select name='data{}' id='data_file'>".$select2."</select>";  
                          mysqli_close($dbLink);
                           }
                               ?> 

                     </td>
                   </tr>
                  <tr>
                       <td>
                           <label for="footer">Select Footer:</label>
                       </td>
                       <td><?php
                              $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display');
                                   
                                    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                         die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                               }
                               else{              
                                     $sql = "select footer_name from screen_footer";
                                       $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                       $select3 .= "<option  value='select'>Select</option>\n";
                                       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                       $select3 .= "<option>".$row['footer_name']."</option>\n";
                                                                  }
                                   echo "<select name='footer' id='footer_file'>".$select3."</select>";  
                         mysqli_close($dbLink);
                           }
                          ?>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
              
               <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" id="submit" />
                  </center>
               </form>
   ```

```js
<script>
 function addrow(x){
           alert(x);

        for (var l=1; l <= x-1; l++){
                                   $(function() {
   var k=4;
                                              //  var addDiv1 = $('#table_row');
                                            //  var k = $('#table_row p').size() + 1;
var index = 4;
newRow = "<tr>" +
                "<td><label>Select Pagelayout"+l+": </label></td><td><?php $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display'); 
                    // Check connection
                            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                      die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                            }
                            else{              
                                  $sql = "SELECT name FROM layout";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                     $select4 .= "<option  value='select'>". select ."</option>";
                                     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                      $select4 .= "<option>".$row['name']."</option>";
                                              }
                                    echo "<select name='layout.'l'.' id='layout.'l'.'>".$select4."</select>";
                      mysqli_close($dbLink);
                        }?></td></tr>"+
                "<tr><td><label>Select Data"+l+": </label></td><td><?php $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display'); 
                    // Check connection
                            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                      die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                            }
                            else{              
                                  $sql = "select file_name from data_file";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                    $select5 .= "<option  value='select'>Select</option>";
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    $select5 .= "<option>".$row['file_name']."</option>";
                                                               }
                                echo "<select name='data.'l'.' id='data.'l'.'>".$select5."</select>";  
                      mysqli_close($dbLink);
                        }?></td></tr>";


$('#myTable > tbody > tr').eq(k).after(newRow);
     //  $('#myTable > tbody > tr').eq(k-1).after(newRow);

    return false;
           
                                                                });
            
        }  scrnselection.h.value=l;  
           alert(l);
                       
          
             }
```

```html
<form name="scrnselection" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
            <center>
          <?php if(!empty($error)) echo '<div class="error"><b>'.$error.'</b></div>'; ?>  
            <?php if(!empty($accept)) echo '<div class="accept"><b>'.$accept.'</b></div>'; ?> 

        <input name="h" type="hidden" id="h" value="0" />
        <label id="lab" style="visibility:hidden;"></label> <br/> 
            <table id="mytable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="multiname">Enter the name of screen:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="multiname" id="name" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                     
               <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="scrn">Select no. of screen:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <select name="scr" id="scr" onchange="addrow($(this).val());">
                                <option value="select" selected>select</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
     </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="header">Select Header:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <?php
                        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display'); 
                    // Check connection
                            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                      die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                            }
                            else{              
                                  $sql = "select header_name from screen_header";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                    $select .= "<option  value='select'>Select</option>\n";
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    $select .= "<option>".$row['header_name']."</option>\n";
                                                               }
                                echo "<select name='header' id='header_file'>".$select."</select>";  
                      mysqli_close($dbLink);
                        }
                            ?>            
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                            <td>
                        <label for="pagelayout">Select Pagelayout:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php

                          $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display');
                                
                                 if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                      die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                            }
                                  else {
                                    $sql="SELECT name FROM layout";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                    $select1 .= "<option  value='select'>Select</option>\n";
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    $select1 .= "<option>".$row['name']."</option>\n";
                                       }
                                    echo "<select name='layout[]' id='layout_file'>".$select1."</select>";  
                           mysqli_close($dbLink);
                          }   
                        ?>       
                    </td>
                </tr>
               
               <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="data">Select Data:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                        <?php
                            $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display');
                                
                                 if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                      die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                            }
                            else{              
                                  $sql = "select file_name from data_file";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                    $select2 .= "<option  value='select'>Select</option>\n";
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    $select2 .= "<option>".$row['file_name']."</option>\n";
                                                               }
                                echo "<select name='data{}' id='data_file'>".$select2."</select>";  
                       mysqli_close($dbLink);
                        }
                            ?> 

                  </td>
                </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="footer">Select Footer:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php
                           $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display');
                                
                                 if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                                      die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                            }
                            else{              
                                  $sql = "select footer_name from screen_footer";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));
                                    $select3 .= "<option  value='select'>Select</option>\n";
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    $select3 .= "<option>".$row['footer_name']."</option>\n";
                                                               }
                                echo "<select name='footer' id='footer_file'>".$select3."</select>";  
                      mysqli_close($dbLink);
                        }
                       ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
           
            <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" id="submit" />
               </center>
            </form>
```

```php
>    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
>    {
        $screen_name = $_REQUEST['multiname'];
        $screen_scr = $_POST['scr'];
        $screen_header = $_POST['header'];
    //$screen_layout = $_POST['layout'];
   // $screen_data =  $_POST['data'];
    $screen_footer = $_POST['footer'];
    $num = $_POST['h'];

   echo $num;


   $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'display');

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                                            }
$sql="SELECT screen_name from `multi_screen` WHERE name='$screen_name'";
     $check=mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql);


 if(mysqli_num_rows($check)>=1)

$error= "Name already exist!";


else
  { 
 for($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++){
if(isset($_REQUEST['layout$i']))
{
   $screen_layout = $_POST['layout$i'];

   echo $screen_layout;
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['data$i']))
{ 
        $screen_data = $_REQUEST['data$i'];
} 
 $sql1="INSERT INTO `multi_screen` (screen_name, screen_scr, screen_header, screen_layout, screen_footer) VALUES ('$screen_name','$screen_scr','$screen_header','$screen_layout','$screen_footer')";

   $result1 = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql1) or die (mysqli_error($dbLink));

     if (!$result1)
        {
         die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" >  alert(\"Problem ocuured with server. Please try again later.\");   </script>";
                }

   else $accept= "Data Inserted !Continue with the process.";
}

 mysqli_close($dbLink);
  //   header("Location: layout.php");
  }
}
```

Comment: You have [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) problems

Comment: Hi, my database issue is solved.I'll put all the elements in array so now its working. But my other 2 problem exist please help me with that